# Restructuring nested ajax calls so variables work

Tags: ajax, variables, inheritance, nested

My "value" variables below are not being inherited into the second call.  What is the recommended way to reconstruct this so that it works?

First, I get all the data from our data table.  Then, I need to get pending changes from a completely different database (change control).  I need to display the second data if it exists.

```
function getData(appid) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'services/getData',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { 'appid': appid },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var field1Value = data.field1;
        var field2Value = data.field2;
        var field3Value = data.field3;

        //get pending changes
        $.ajax({
            url: 'services/getPendingChanges',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { 'appid': appid },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data2) {
                if (data2.field1 <> '') { field1value = data2.field1 };
                if (data2.field2 <> '') { field1value = data2.field2 };
                if (data2.field2 <> '') { field1value = data2.field2 };
            },
            complete: function () {
                //set data in UI regardless of whether it came from getData or getPendingChanges
                $('#txtField1').html(field1value);
                $('#txtField2').html(field2value);
                $('#txtField3').html(field3value);
            }
        })
    }
  })
}
```

of course when I do this, all the "*value" variables are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure whether this will help you at all (and it probably won't), but this is what I've learned in my time in Javascript. But the nature of anon classes in javascript are so that you can use them without worry of variable collisions. The easiest way is that you funnel up to a higher scope variable to use later. But that's generally bad practice... So you could throw a wrapper around all that...

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you have in mind with the wrapper idea?  I tried moving the variable declarations up to the function level and have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up hiding the fields then calling the second ajax from the complete of the first.  I set the fields in the success of the first call and also in the success of the second call, *if they exist*.  Then I unhide them in the complete of the second.

```
function getData(appid) {
  $('#txtField1').hide();
  $('#txtField2').hide();
  $('#txtField3').hide();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'services/getData',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { 'appid': appid },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var field1Value = data.field1;
        var field2Value = data.field2;
        var field3Value = data.field3;
        $('#txtField1').html(field1value);
        $('#txtField2').html(field2value);
        $('#txtField3').html(field3value);
    },
    complete: function () {
        //get pending changes
        $.ajax({
            url: 'services/getPendingChanges',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { 'appid': appid },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data2) {
                if (data2.field1 <> '') { 
                    field1value = data2.field1 
                    $('#txtField1').html(field1value);
                };
                if (data2.field2 <> '') { 
                    field2value = data2.field2 
                    $('#txtField2').html(field2value);
                };
                if (data2.field3 <> '') { 
                    field3value = data2.field3 
                    $('#txtField3').html(field3value);
                };
            },
            complete: function () {
                $('#txtField1').show();
                $('#txtField2').show();
                $('#txtField3').show();
            }
        })
    }
  })
}
```

Ultimately instead of hiding them I would swap them out with a loading indicator.  Also, I realize the BEST thing to do would be have a single web service that did all the logic in the background and just returned the appropriate data.